# Solving thousands of ODEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Hi I'm trying to solve many coupled differential equations  with NDSolve but it has been impossible. So, How many coupled ODEs can i solve with this function (NDSolve)? Can I use other functions? should I change some options like the precision ? or shoul I change to another programation language?. This is an example of the whole code with only 10 ecuations:

```
NDSolve[{
  Derivative[1][p1][t] == -2 p1[t] + p45[t] + p46[t] + p5[t] + p7[t], 
  Derivative[1][p2][t] == -2 p2[t] + p46[t] + p6[t] + p8[t], 
  Derivative[1][p3][t] == -2 p3[t] + p47[t] + p48[t] + p7[t], 
  Derivative[1][p4][t] == -2 p4[t] + p48[t] + p8[t], 
  Derivative[1][p5][t] == 2 p11[t] + p49[t] - 3 p5[t] + p50[t] + 2 p9[t], 
  Derivative[1][p6][t] == 2 p10[t] + 2 p12[t] + p2[t] + p50[t] - 3 p6[t], 
  Derivative[1][p7][t] == p1[t] + 2 p11[t] + p51[t] + p52[t] - 4 p7[t], 
  Derivative[1][p8][t] == 2 p12[t] + p2[t] + p4[t] + p52[t] - 4 p8[t],
  Derivative[1][p9][t] == 3 p13[t] + 3 p15[t] + p53[t] + p54[t] - 4 p9[t], 
  Derivative[1][p10][t] == -4 p10[t] + 3 p14[t] + 3 p16[t] + p54[t] + 
    p6[t], ....., p1[0] == 0.00206612`, p2[0] == 0.00206612`, 
  p3[0] == 0.00206612`, p4[0] == 0.00206612`, p5[0] == 0.00206612`, 
  p6[0] == 0.00206612`, p7[0] == 0.00206612`, p8[0] == 0.00206612`, 
  p9[0] == 0.00206612`, p10[0] == 0.00206612`, ....}, {p1[t], p2[t], 
  p3[t], p4[t], p5[t], p6[t], p7[t], p8[t], p9[t], p10[t], ...}, {t, 
  0, 100}]
```

Comment: Without seeing the ODE system, we cannot say anything.

Comment: Thank you for including the equations. Can you show us the whole code that you tried, i.e. the full call to `NDSolve` that you used?

Comment: How many equations? What goes wrong?

Comment: You seem to show only 10 equations but have 54 dependent variables (p1 through p54).  At least they are linear.  Why not try just 2 equations, two variables pt1 and pt2, then 5, then 15, then 20, and so on and see what happens.

Comment: "Thousands of ODEs" isn't a problem at all. If you're having difficulty, please show us the complete code sample.